# Divisible and imply

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I do not get why this is false:

$$a \mid bc \implies a \mid b\text{ OR }b \mid c$$

If $a$ is $12$, $b$ is $3$, and $c$ is $2$, then $12$ is divisible by both $bc$ and $b$. Should it not be true?

While this is true:

$$a \mid 9\text{ AND }a \mid 15 \implies a \mid 6$$
If I use $90$ instead of $a$, it is true, if I use $45$, it is false.

So why is the first false while the second is true?

Comment: You have the meaning of | backwards. $12\mid 3\cdot2$ is false.

Comment: $a\mid b$ means that $a$ "divides" $b$, which is the same thing as saying that $b$ is a multiple of $a$.  For example $3\mid 12$, $4\mid 12$, $6\mid 12$ and $12\mid 12$, but $24\not\mid 12$.  Another way of writing it is $a\mid b\iff \exists k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $b=a\cdot k$

Comment: Something else to point out, is that It is sometimes possible that $a\mid bc$ as well as $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$ (*or $b\mid c$ as you have written which appears to be a typo*), but just because it is true in one specific case does not mean that it is true in all cases.  We say a statement about all numbers is false if there is at least one example of numbers for which the statement is false.

Comment: Sorry I believe I have understood the whole thing backwards. When I say 12 is divisible by 3*2 it should look like this 3*2|12 and not 12|3*2

Answer (score 0):

The first one is false, because $4\mid(6\times10)$, in spite of the fact that $4\nmid6$ and $4\nmid10$.

The second one is true because if $a\mid9$ and $a\mid15$, then $a\mid(15-9)$, which means that $a\mid6$.

Comment: so I should look at it like this 4 | (6 x 10), 4 ∤ 6 and 4 ∤ 10, and not like this 4 | 6x10 which is 4|60?

Comment: @AndroidCoder I do not understand your question. I proved that the assertion “$a\mid bc\implies a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$” is false by providing an example in which it doesn't hold.

Comment: Sorry I believe I have understood the whole thing backwards. When I say 12 is divisible by 3*2 it should look like this 3*2|12 and not 12|3*2

Answer (score 0):

There are two facts at play here: one, if $b$ and $c$ are *coprime* (and this assumption is critical) then $a|bc$ does in fact imply $a|b$ or $a|c$. Two, if $a|b$ and $a|c$, then $a|gcd(b,c)$.

Try to come up with proofs of these, and exhibit examples in which they fail when the hypothesese are not met.